# Apply function to section of armadillo vector

Tags: c++, armadillo

I would like to calculate some summary functions (e.g. mean) on a section of a column of an armadillo matrix. Key is not to create a temporary copy of the data.

This works with entire columns, using `unsafe_col`:

```
arma::mat x;
double d = mean(x.unsafe_col(0));
```

To obtain a section of a vector, I could use:

```
x.col(0).subvec(0,100);
```

However, this creates a copy of the vector data, which I want to avoid.

What would be the most efficient way to apply the armadillo-provided functions to sections of column vectors? Performance is absolutely critical in this applications.

One way I found was to construct a vector with pointers to the underlying memory, using what is called an "[advanced constructor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col)" in the armadillo documentation, but first getting pointers to double for the column start and the adding offsets for start and end just to create a shorter vector seems quite a hack...

UPDATE: Here is an example of the behaviour:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

arma::mat m( {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}});

const arma::vec view1() {
    return m.unsafe_col(0).subvec(0,2);
}

const arma::vec view2() {
    double *start = &m[0,0];
    const int n = 3;
    return arma::vec(start, 3, false, false);
}

int main() {

    std::cout << &m(0,0) << " " << &m(1,0) << " " << &m(0,1) << std::endl;

    auto v1(view1());
    auto v2(view2());
    std::cout << &v1(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &v2(0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which returns, for example:

```
0x56419b070170 0x56419b070178 0x56419b070190
0x7ffcb36f7510
0x56419b070170
```

So view1() created a copy, but view2() did not.

Comment: Looking at the Armadillo source code, `x.col(0).subvec(0,100)` doesn't necessarily create a copy. It just provides a subview. Whether a copy is made depends on the function that you feed the subview to, orientation of data, etc. For the `mean()` function, no copy seems to be done for subviews of vectors.

Comment: You are right, subvec indeed does not create a copy. In my case I would like to store that subvec in a new variable (or return it from a function) without triggering a (deep) copy, and that is what I don't achieve. See update above.